# Limit of the convolution of derivative of Gaussian heat kernel

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits-and-convergence

I'm looking for the following limit:
$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\sqrt{\varepsilon}}^{\sqrt{\varepsilon}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon^{3/2}}\left(-1+\frac{x^2}{\varepsilon}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\varepsilon}}l(a+x)dx=???$$
Where $l$ is a bounded and nice function ($l\in C^{\infty}$) with $l(a)\neq 0$. We remark that
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\varepsilon}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\varepsilon}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\varepsilon^{3/2}}\left(-1+\frac{x^2}{\varepsilon}\right)e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\varepsilon}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $h:=\sqrt\varepsilon$ and denoting the standard normal pdf by $f$, we see that the integral under the limit sign is 
$$\frac1{h^3}\int_{-h}^h f''(x/h)l(a+x)\,dx
=\frac1{h^2}\,I(h),$$
where 
$$I(h):=\int_{-1}^1 f''(u)l(a+hu)\,du\underset{h\downarrow0}\longrightarrow
\int_{-1}^1 f''(u)l(a)\,du \\ 
=2\int_0^1 f''(u)l(a)\,du 
=2l(a)f'(1)=-l(a)\sqrt{\frac2{\pi e}};$$
here we used the dominated convergence theorem. 
So, the integral under the limit sign is 
$$-\frac{l(a)+o(1)}{h^2}\,\sqrt{\frac2{\pi e}}
=-\frac{l(a)+o(1)}\varepsilon\,\sqrt{\frac2{\pi e}}.$$
So, the limit of this integral is $-\infty$ if $l(a)>0$ and $\infty$ if $l(a)<0$.